# How to create unique serial number strings in a particular format?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, guid, uuid

I would like to populate my SQL Server table with some serial numbers to give to other people. They're just going to be UUIDs in effect which are related to peoples email addresses.

I can see that ColdFusion provide the `CreateUUID` function but it generates an ID with the format of:

> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

That is following a 8-4-4-16 structure. I just want something simple like a 3-3-3 format which will be unique for each row in the table (that is, each customer).

What would be the best way to tackle this? I don't mind doing it within SQL or ColdFusion, but I'm not sure how to get either of them to auto-generate such a string for me. SQL Server has the `NEWID()` function but again it generates large strings not in the format I want.

Is there some way to force SQL's `NewID()` or CF's `CreateUUID` to create a unique serial with a 3-3-3 format?

Comment: (Edit) Not sure if you mean nine (9) digits total or same length uuid, just formatted into three (3) groups instead of four or five. If the latter, I *think* you could just generate the uuid and adjust the hyphens. I am not 100% certain though. Otherwise, is there a specific issue or problem with the existing formats? While you could certainly DIY, it would require ensuring the generated values truly were unique - not just random. It seems a bit like reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: They're going to be used as voucher codes so they can't be too long. Something like "XSY-20B-P7O" is better for my needs than a huge default UUID.

Comment: Unless you generate millions of IDs, even truncated UUIDs are very unlikely to collide. Reason for that is how the timestamp/clock is considered in the first groups. Just get rid of the `-` and use the first 9 characters.

Comment: If the value does not need be *globally* unique, and nine characters contains enough combinations, that would probably work. Just do not rely on it being unlikely.  If a non-unique value would break the code, be sure to add a `unique` constraint to the table (and retry code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, it will generate the format you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @Value = NEWID()
SELECT @Value
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Value,1,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@Value,10,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@Value,30,3)
```

Comment: The format sure, but is it guaranteed to be unique? I suspect not.

Comment: @Leigh, ur correct, there is no guarantee that this will yield unique serial numbers.

Comment: You can try newsequentialid() instead for unique values [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

Serial numbers should be unique. One way to guarantee a unique serial number for your email addresses is format an IDENTITY column. If your Email table doesn't already have an IDENTITY column add one. Lets says it's named Email_ID, then the following expression will give you a string in the form of XXX-XXX-XXX that is guaranteed to be unique to the email table.

```
SELECT
  STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(Email_ID AS VARCHAR(9)), 9), 4, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')
FROM
  EmailTable
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't see where is the column name `Email_ID` in that code?

Comment: @volume_one. Ooops, fixed now.

Comment: This is not quite what I had in mind. I really needed something more random like "SYO-001-AXR". Although it doesn't serve much purpose, I also didn't want people second-guessing what the combination could be easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a random 9-character string and afterwards check if it's unique in your customer/people table. If it's not -> create a new random string and check again. (loop until it's unique).

I created 2 functions for this, one that generates a random string of 9 characters and another one that uses the first function to create a string and then checks a table to see if this string exists in a particular column.

Random string function:

```
<cffunction name="makeRandomString" returnType="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="codeLength" type="numeric" required="no" default="9">

   <cfset var chars = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ">
   <cfset var length = codeLength>
   <cfset var result = "">
   <cfset var i = "">
   <cfset var char = "">

   <cfscript>
   for(i=1; i <= length; i++) {
      char = mid(chars, randRange(1, len(chars)),1);
      result&=char;
   }
   </cfscript>

   <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

Function that creates a random string and makes sure it's unique in a particular column of a particular table:

```
<cffunction name="createUniqueCode" returnType="string" output="false">

    <cfargument name="tableName" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="columnName" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="codeLength" type="numeric" required="no" default="9">

    <cfset ordercode = 0>
    <cfset ordercodecheck = 0>
    <cfloop condition="ordercodecheck eq 0">
        <cfset ordercode = #makeRandomString('#codeLength#')#>
        <cfquery name="findCode" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        select #kolomNaam# from #tableName# where #columnName# = '#ordercode#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfif findCode.recordcount eq 0>
            <cfset ordercodecheck = 1>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn ordercode>

</cffunction>
```

Now you can loop for x-times and generate x random codes that will always be unique. ("myColumnName" in the example below is the name of the column that contains the unique code)

```
<cfloop from="1" to="100" index="i">
    <cfset newCode = createUniqueCode(tableName='myTableName',columnName='myColumnName')>

    <!--- insert what to do with new code here (f.e. an insert query) the "newCode" variable holds the new unique code. --->
</cfloop>
```

I hope this was of any help to you.

Cheers

Comment: Keep in mind web applications are multi-threaded. In a busy application, duplicates are still possible due to race conditions. A more bullet-proof approach is to create a `unique` constraint on the db table. Then try/catch constraint exceptions and use that as the trigger to retry. Also a) do not forget to var/local scope ALL function local variables b) use cfqueryparam and c) use caution using variables for table/columns as it can pose a SQL injection risk depending on the source of the values.

Comment: *I created 2 functions for this,* When posting [borrowed code](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/03/14/Using-CAPTCHA-in-ColdFusion-with-reload-powered-by-jQuery/), please be sure to cite the source, both as a courtesy to the author and so it is not viewed as plagiarism.

Comment: No problem Leigh. Seems I forgot where I got that part from since I've been using it for years. My answer wasn't meant as getting "recognition" for writing some code, just to help out fellow programmer. I'll try and remember to give credit in the future.